# Statistical test to use for multiple categorical independent variables, multiple correlated continuous dependent variables?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multivariate-analysis

I'm pretty much a beginner in Stats so please excuse me if my question doesn't seem too hard to answer.
I have a dataset consisting of variables `Treatment` (categorical variable with levels Control, A, B, A+B), `Year` (categorical variable consisting of 3 consecutive years), `Coverage of an invasive species (in %)` (which we wish to eventually reduce), `Coverage of native species A`, `Coverage of native species B` (we want to see an increase in both of these variables), `Coverage of dangerous species C`, `Coverage of dangerous species D` (we want to see a decrease in these), and a few other technical measurements of the land which are of little interest. All the coverages of a single record add up to 100%, and the dataset is quite small with just 30 records in total. I wish to determine statistically which group in the `Treatment` column would help to achieve most of the desired effects as mentioned above, and not too sure which direction I should head to do this. After doing some self-research, I have 2 available options that I'm considering:

1. Using MANCOVA with Treatment and Year as explanatory variables, and `Coverage of an invasive species (in %)`, `Coverage of native species A`, `Coverage of native species B` as multiple dependent variables.
2. Someone also advised me I could try experimenting with PCA for this problem, but I am not sure how I could go about using PCA for this. Since PCA is mostly used for dimensionality reduction, would I need to wide-pivot the Treatment column into separate columns for each treatment, then one-hot encode them, then use PCA with target being `Coverage of an invasive species (in %)`, `Coverage of native species A`, `Coverage of native species B` to find the best treatments (principal components)?

Any advice on how I should approach this problem is greatly appreciated!

Comment: MANCOVA seems like an interesting approach, but I am not sure that it will handle the compositional aspect of your data.